# Scifi anthology (circa 1970-1975) with the words "science fiction for people who don't like science fiction" on the front or rear cover

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I have tried Library of Congress online, WorldCat, Google, Google images of book covers (tip: these tend to never show the back cover), this website. So far, nothing.

Perhaps the words

> SCIENCE FICTION FOR PEOPLE WHO DON'T LIKE SCIENCE FICTION

appeared in a display advertisement in a USA-based science fiction periodical. Perhaps the words appeared only on the back of the dust jacket or paperback. Book was a compilation, various authors collected.

Have already tried these variations: SF, SCI-FI, SCIENCE FICTION. DO NOT, DON'T. Nothing. Probably not a British book, but possible. Display advertisement never appeared in a UK science fiction periodical. Book probably from USA-based publisher. Possibly a mainstream publishing house, though this seems unlikely.

Book could be late 1960's.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that this doesn't give a decent result on google with the words you've posted. Not *very* surprised, since it's a reasonable phrase to search for without meaning a specific book, but still..

Comment: So the posted answer is not the book you were looking for, and we should keep on looking? The one you want definitely had the exact words "don't like", not "hate"?

Answer (score 27):

This seems too obvious, but [*Science Fiction for People Who Hate Science Fiction*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?36069) is the title of an anthology edited by [Terry Carr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terry_Carr), first published in hardcover by Doubleday in 1966

[image]

and reprinted in paperback by Funk & Wagnalls in 1968:

[image]